# GCP Firewall Issue with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

tried to create firewall-rules in GCP using Terraform, getting below error.
Error creating Firewall: googleapi: Error 404T he resource 'projects/project_name/global/networks/vpc_name.name' was not found, notFound
tried to change vpc name but getting same error no changes in the error output.
please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: Can you please edit your original post and add your TF code?

Answer (score 2):

Per @caio-t, please include as many details as possible when asking questions.

In this case, it would be prudent to include your terraform script as this provides precise details on what you're doing and helps folks provide an appropriate answer.

Per the documentation for [`google_compute_firewall`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_firewall) if you're looking to add a firewall called `freddie` to the `default` (!) network for any source address (`0.0.0.0/0`) for `tcp` on `8080` to target VM's tagged `http-server`, you can:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 3.75"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  project     = "[[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]]"
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "default" {
  name    = "freddie"
  network = "default"

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["8080"]
  }

  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  target_tags = ["http-server"]
}
```